# What are the underlying physical principles of a constant current power source?

Tags: current-source

I´m currently looking for a led driver to drive a 34,25 W High-Power LED at 38.06 V / 900 mA. Browsing trough various online shops i found a constant current source and i don`t get how it works.

The datasheet says the rated output voltage is 27 to 54 V, the rated output current is 1050 ma. What are the physical principles, that would allow this device to drive my led ? I don`t understand how the voltage would adapt based on the needed voltage of the LED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constant current power supply will have a current shunt.  This is a low value, but accurate resistor.  When current flow across it, you get a voltage drop that is fairly small, but measurable.

This is used as feedback to push the voltage up or down to reach the set current.  This can be with a switching or a linear regulation.

In the simplest sense, a common variable linear regulator, like a LM317, can be used.  The output is adjusted such that the reference pin is 1.25V.  This is typically a voltage divider with resistors to make the proper ratio of the output voltage to be 1.25V.

In a constant current supply, you would amplify the voltage of the current shunt, such that it would reach 1.25V at the correct current.

When you run a shunt that gets to 1.25V directly, the design is very simple:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYrDaa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The current is coming through the OUT, then the 12.5 ohm resistor.  There is a very small current flowing in ADJ.  The current is changed to keep the voltage drop between OUT and ADJ to 1.25V, thus giving 100 mA.  (This can only change within the driving capabilities of the Supply voltage and the LM317.)  Can't figure out how to show current with DC simulation, but Ohms Law gives it to you.

The best designs are a switching supply that uses the feedback to generate that output voltage.  This has a much higher efficiency than a linear design, but slightly harder to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The device outputs a constant current as long as the voltage is in the compliance range of 27 to 54 volts.  The current is measured and used as feedback in the same manner that the output voltage is measured and used as feedback to control voltage sources.  If the current is too low, the output is increased and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give a link to the datasheet, but in general the voltage adapts through current feedback. The current through the LED string is measured, compared to a reference (That is equivalent to 1050mA) and the voltage is adjusted to maintain the current equal to the reference.  A servo acts to increase or decrease the voltage to keep the current at the desired setpoint.